# KeePass application with synchronization support on a Mac?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, password

I'm looking for a KeePass application for use on Mac OSX.

KeePassX and KyPass 3 but both lack support for synchronization of KeePass 2 (.kdbx) databases.

- KeePassX will just plain overwrite the database.
- KyPass 3 will do you the courtesy of alerting you of a potential data loss before overwriting a database.
- [KeePass](http://keepass2.openix.be/) is a third option, but I have't not been able to get the application to work, let alone test synchronization.

What Mac OS X apps support **synchronization** of the kdbx database that stores credentials in this open source format?

Comment: I got a message from the KyPass developer, telling me that synchronization support is "in the pipe :)"

Answer (score 1):

[MacPass](https://macpass.github.io/) is an open-source KeePass client for OS X that is able to sync KDBX files.  I came across this looking for an answer to this question myself, finding no real satisfactory answers elsewhere.

Comment: It supports sync, *but* only for local files - there is no built-in support for FTP, SFTP, FTPS, SCP etc

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the .kdbx-file. 
The solution is to download and install [KeePass Classic 1.27](http://keepass.info/download.html) on your Windows machine, **which still saves the database file in the older .kdb format**. This .kdb file can be cross-opened in both Keepass Classic and KeePassX on your Mac.

To make them synced across devices I would recommed using Dropbox in which you save your .kdb database file. Obviously this is not a real-time syncing application so you cannot have the apps open on all devices at the same time and see the changes. It is a save-close-sync procedure inbetween. However it works flawlessly this way.

Equally, now this dropbox-synced .kdb-file now works on iOS through the excellent little [PassDrop](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/passdrop/id431185109?mt=8) app :-)